# Find next row with specific value in a given row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The table I have now looks something like this. Each row has a time value (on which the table is sorted in ascending order), and two values which can be replicated across rows:

```
Key      TimeCall     R_ID      S_ID
-------------------------------------------
1          100          40        A
2          101          50        B
3          102          40        C
4          103          50        D
5          104          60        A
6          105          40        B
```

I would like to return something like this, wherein for each row, a JOIN is applied such that the `S_ID` and `Time_Call` of the next row that shares that row's `R_ID` is displayed (or is NULL if that row is the last instance of a given `R_ID`). Example:

```
Key        TimeCall     R_ID      S_ID      NextTimeCall      NextS_ID
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1          100          40        A         102               C
2          101          50        B         103               D
3          102          40        C         105               B
4          103          50        D         NULL              NULL
5          104          60        A         NULL              NULL
6          105          40        B         NULL              NULL
```

Any advice on how to do this would be much appreciated. Right now I'm joining the table on itself and staggering the key on which I'm joining, but I know this won't work for the instance that I've outlined above:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Table.*, Table2.TimeCall AS NextTimeCall, Table2.S_ID AS NextS_ID
    FROM tempdb..#Table AS Table
        INNER JOIN tempdb..#Table AS Table2
        ON Table.TimeCall + 1 = Table2.TimeCall
```

So if anyone could show me how to do this such that it can call rows that aren't just consecutive, much obliged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) function:

```
SELECT * 
, LEAD(TimeCall) OVER (PARTITiON BY R_ID ORDER BY [Key]) AS NextTimeCall
, LEAD(S_ID) OVER (PARTITiON BY R_ID ORDER BY [Key]) AS NextS_ID
FROM Table2
ORDER BY [Key]
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f313c/1)

Comment: Awesome. This seems to be what I'm looking for, so I'll review the query output and see that it is; but for right now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is only test example I had close by ... but i think it could help you out, just adapt it to your case, it uses Lag and Lead ... and it's for SQL Server

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL drop table #Test
create table #Test (id int, value int)

insert into #Test (id, value)
values
(1, 1),
(1, 2), 
(1, 3)

select id, 
    value, 
    lag(value, 1, 0) over (order by id) as [PreviusValue], 
    lead(Value, 1, 0) over (order by id) as [NextValue] 
from #Test
```

Results are

```
id  value   PreviusValue    NextValue
1     1         0               2   
1     2         1               3
1     3         2               0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an OUTER APPLY to select the top 1 value that has the same R_ID as the first Query and has a higher Key field

Just change the TableName to the actual name of your table in both parts of the query

```
SELECT a.*, b.TimeCall as NextTimeCall, b.S_ID as NextS_ID FROM
    (
    SELECT * FROM TableName as a
    ) as a
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 FROM TableName as b
    WHERE a.R_ID = b.R_ID
    AND a.Key > B.Key
    ORDER BY Key ASC
    ) as b
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

For older versions, here is one trick using `Outer Apply`

```
SELECT a.*, 
       nexttimecall, 
       nexts_id 
FROM   table1 a 
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 timecall,s_id 
                    FROM   table1 b 
                    WHERE  a.r_id = b.r_id 
                           AND a.[key] < b.[key] 
                    ORDER  BY [key] ASC) oa (nexttimecall, nexts_id)
```

- **[LIVE DEMO](http://rextester.com/TVZR94565)**

**Note :** It is better to avoid reserved keywords(`Key`) as column/table names.